# What is the 3D radiation pattern of this chip antenna?

Tags: wireless, antenna

I know that the 3D radiation pattern of an antenna could be found by knowing the xy, xz and yz plane cuts and vice-versa. This process is pretty straight forward for a dipole antenna which has a 3D radiation pattern in a shape of donut. But I am not able to find the 3D radiation pattern for a chip antenna that has the following cuts.

[image]

I am not an antenna guru I just know the basics. So I would appreciate if anybody could help me with the following points.

**1. Drawing the 3D radiation pattern for this chip antenna taking into consideration the antenna's physical orientation**

**2. Finding the point of the maximum gain (should I find this value according to the vertical plane or the horizontal one?)**

**3. I know that for two dipole antennas to get the maximum energy both of them should be side by side and in parallel to each other. But when using a chip antenna and a dipole one how should be the orientation?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calculating a radiation pattern is not a trivial task, except for simple cases like the dipole antenna. It requires find solutions to complex differential equations. You would need to run the shape through a simulator to find the answer...

Comment: The above comment is true, although for wire like antennas, there is an easy to use, free simulator called NEC. Several programs include drawing front ends.

Answer (score 1):

Your quest is certainly in the advanced antenna simulation space.

Mention of [NEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Electromagnetics_Code) based simulation could provide a solution, however given the chip sized antenna  the numeric precision of NEC would probably mislead.
I use an EM simulator called [HOBBIES](https://hobbies-em.com/), where it is straightforward (but time consuming) to model your concept design in 3D, and get incredibly accurate simulations.. it happily runs on laptops thru to supercomputers..

The alternative is to simply probe the response of a working antenna, cognizant of near field issues.. again, not a simple task if you desire accuracy.